# Adding controls to a different form

Tags: c#, forms, controls

I have a couple of forms, and I want to be able to add a button to a certain form, no matter where the code is.

Normally I'd do something like `this.Controls.Add(button)`, but I don't want it to be added to that form. I've tried doing something like `Form1 frm = new Form1()` and `frm.Controls.Add(button)`, But that didn't work either. How do I need to write it?

This code doesn't work, the form is still blank

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Size = new Size(50,50);
b.Location = new Point(50,50);
new Form1().Controls.Add(b);
```

There are no errors, but nothing is added.

I have found a kind of work around.

```
Control ctrl = this;
ctrl.Controls.Add(b);
```

This works, But I'd rather have a way to specify exactly which form to add it to

Comment: `Didn't work` is not problem description. Please be more specific and add more details to your question.

Comment: Nothing was added, the form is just blank

Comment: Post a short piece of code that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Size = new Size(50,50);
b.Location = new Point(50,50);
new Form1().Controls.Add(b); // This will do nothing you want.
```

Adding control to a form will add it to the single instance on which you run it, not to the form in general.

Try this:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
Button b = new Button();
...
form.Controls.Add(b);
form.ShowDialog(); // Or .Show()

Form1 anotherForm = new Form1();
anotherForm.ShowDialog(); // This instance will NOT have the added button
```

If you're doing this from another form, you can also try this:

```
// Constructor
this._otherForm = new Form1(); // save reference of the other form, to be able to add controls to it later

// Anywhere in the code
this._otherForm.Show(); // will display the other form

// On user action, for example on button click
this._otherForm.Controls.Add(c); // will add the control c to the other form
```